# Hibernate - component class not found

Tags: java, hibernate

Does anyone know what this is all about:

component class not found

with Hibernate?

I got this error How can i solve this issue..?

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: component class not found: EventGeofenceId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've referenced a class named EventGeofenceId somewhere in your configuration but didn't create the Java source.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable guidence.. I solve the problem.. I already create the java source code.I have lot of packages in my project , but the problem is i dont mention the source location(ie com.example.EventGeofenceId) in my hbm file. so its difficult to find the source location.. That is the reason i got that error.. Now i changed it.Its working. Thanks

Comment: So if the answer helped - why not vote it up?  I'd prefer that to your thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing some hibernate jars in classpath.